# Big-O of these two functions

Tags: algorithm, loops, recursion, big-o, time-complexity

Can someone help me find the Big-O of these two functions:

```
int sum(int A[], int i, int n) {
    if (n == 1)
        return A[i];
    return sum(A, i, n/2) + sum(A, i + n/2, (n+1)/2);
}
```

and the 'sort' function of:

```
void swap(int& a, int& b) {
    int temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp;
}

void swapMin(int A[], const int& index) {
    int indexMin = index;
    for (int i = index-1; i >= 0; --i)
        if (A[i] < A[indexMin])
          indexMin = i;

    swap(A[index], A[indexMin]);
}

void sort(int A[], int n) {
    for (int i = n-1; i >= 0; --i)
        swapMin(A, i);
}
```

I believe the first is O(1) and the second is O(n) but I'm not sure if that is correct.

Comment: You have to ask a more precise question - StackOverflow is not for asking people to do your work for you; describe what you have tried and where you are stuck. FIY, first is O(n - i), second is O(n^2)

Answer (score 2):

For the first function, you can do this:

[image]

And then you can solve it using **generating functions**.

For the second one, you may use Sigma notation:

[image]